# Active Directory vs Local Account Authentication

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, active-directory

We have developed an app in .Net.  There is a common login page for all users.  Some accounts in the app are set up to authentiate against Active Directory.  Other accounts use a local account to login in (the username and account is stored in the user store of the app).  When a user logs in, how can we differentiate whether the user is authenticating with their AD credentials or if it's a local account.   Local account / username is normally the user's email address.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to require users use their full username. So AD users would either use `username@domain.tld` or `DOMAIN\username` and local account users would not. You would then parse the username and based on the prefix or trailing domain, determine which MembershipProvider to use to authenticate.

Comment: What if the AD login name is the user's AD userprincipalname?  This could possibly clash with a non-AD account's username (email field).  Also, how about user's with the same samAccountName (in different AD domains, etc.).  How would you handle this conflict?

Comment: @user3550534 - You have find *some* token *that the user enters* that differentiates an AD user from the local user. That could be an agreed up on prefix such as "DOMAIN\" that AD users must use and local users must not use. That could be the email domain if the domain used for AD vs. non-AD are 100% mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You should just prioritize one over the other and then check each user database in that order. So if you prioritize your local users then just check if the username is a valid local user, if its not then check it against AD.